# Why does Python floor division return a float when the divisor and/or dividend is a float?

Tags: python, floating-point, precision, arbitrary-precision, floor-division

If I understand correctly, the return value for floor division is always a whole number, even if the dividend and/or divisor are not whole numbers, so why does it not always return an integer.

It's detrimental in my case because converting from a large float to an int instead of having the return value as an arbitrary-precision integer obviously loses precision.

I can't see any function that does float floor division to return an integer. Obviously I could make a function to do so, e.g. by multiplying both values by the same amount so that they're both integers, but it would be a lot slower than a C implementation.

Here's an example: `5.2 // 2` is `2.0` not `2`.

Comment: If you want to do exact integer arithmetic, you shouldn't have floats in the first place; if you can't get around that, then why not just convert them to ints before doing the division?

Comment: Please read [ask]. This question desperately needs an example.

Comment: @JulianKirsch: They're not using `math.floor`. They're using floor division, `//`. `math.floor` is irrelevant here.

Comment: (Still, an example would very much help here. I likely wouldn't have made that error, nor would Julian, with a small snippet in the question.)

Comment: @ShadowRanger Thanks for the correction! I wasn't aware that such operator even exists.

Comment: @superbrain That was a typo. I meant to ask why it doesn't always return an integer, hence the contradiction with the title. I will correct that error now.

Comment: @Chris I have now given a desperately-needed example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In answer to your question *why?*, it is by design, and the rationale for this is in [PEP 238](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0238/):

> Floor division will be implemented in all the Python numeric types,
> and will have the semantics of:
>
> `a // b == floor(a/b)`
>
> except that the result type will be the common
> type into which *a* and *b* are coerced before the operation.
>
> Specifically, if *a* and *b* are of the same type, `a//b` will be of that
> type too. If the inputs are of different types, they are first coerced
> to a common type using the same rules used for all other arithmetic
> operators.
>
> ...
>
> For floating point inputs, the result is a float. For example:
>
> `3.5//2.0 == 1.0`
>
> For complex numbers, `//` raises an exception, since `floor()` of a
> complex number is not allowed.

This PEP dates back to Python 2.2. I've suppressed a paragraph that discusses the now obsolete distinction between `int` and `long`.